# Order By with select query in hibernate

Tags: sql, sql-server, hibernate, hql

I have this SQL server query:

```
SELECT * from DOCUMENTS 
where isdeleted = 1 and deletedBy = 1
ORDER BY (select USERS.FIRSTNAME from USERS where DOCUMENTS.CreatedBy = USERS.DKEY) asc;
```

It works well in SQL Server. But I want to write it is HQL, I try many ways but it doesn't work:

```
hql = "from DOCUMENTS d where d.isdeleted = true and d.deletedBy = true
ORDER BY (select ue.firstname from Users ue where d.createdBy = ue.dkey) asc";
```

Answer (score 0):

If your table design as e relational between `Documents` and `Users` you can sort it by `DOCUMENTS.createdBy.firstname` same as this:

```
SELECT d 
FROM DOCUMENTS d 
WHERE d.isdeleted = true 
AND d.deletedBy = true
ORDER BY d.createdBy.firstname ASC
```